# Send push Notification to Multiple Apps

Tags: ios

I wanted to know if it is possible to send a Push to App A and App B at the same time, and if the user has both apps installed, only one will be shown.

Edit:
I was trying to prevent duplicate Notifications to be shown if the user has both Apps installed. But it seems this is not possible to do on the App side. We will have to come up with something server side to prevent duplicate messages to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app has its own deviceToken on that device. To send pushes to both apps you would need to send the push to both device tokens.  The device will display both notifications.

Comment: is there any way using App Groups to prevent this behavior?